# Calculating the expected value of a weird random variable

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $Z$ is a standard normal random variable, and, for a fixed $x$, set
$$X = \left\{ 
  \begin{array}{l l}
    Z & \quad \text{if $Z>x$}\\
    0 & \quad \text{otherwise}
  \end{array} \right.$$

Show that $$E[X]=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}$$

I tried to tackle it but without success. I hope someone can help me

Comment: It might help to notice the similarities between $E[X]$ and the probability density function of the normal distribution, then compare your definition of $X$ and the definition of the pdf!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write $X=Z\mathbb{1}_{\{Z>x\}}$. Then
$$
\mathbb{E}X = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}y\mathbb{1}_{\{y>x\}} e^{-y^2/2}dy = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{(x,\infty)}ye^{-y^2/2}dy 
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\left[-e^{-y^2/2}\right]_x^{\uparrow\infty}
$$
which gives the result.

Comment: As a matter of fact, useful equality (which holds for _any_ r.v. $X$ in $L_1$):
$$\mathbb{E}X = \int_\mathbb{R} x\mathbb{P}\{X\in dx\}= \int_\mathbb{R} \mathbb{P}\{X > x\}dx$$

Comment: what does $\mathbb{P}\{X\in dx\}$ mean ? I'm sorry if it's a stupid question but I haven't came across such a thing in my courses so far.

Comment: Btw I got it now, thanks for the help.

Comment: Oh, it's the probability that $X$ takes value in the infinitesimal "set" $dx$ around $x$. If $X$ is distributed according to a probability distribution with a pdf $\phi$ (wrt to the Lebesgue measure), it's just "$\phi(x)dx$"; but in general, it could be anything defining a probability distribution (for instance, if $X$ is discrete, e.g. Bernoulli with parameter $1/2$, you would have $\mathbb{P}(X\in dx)=1/2$ if $x\in\{0,1\}$, and $\mathbb{P}(X\in dx)=0$ otherwise)